# How can I Stop/Skip the execution of a particular function for a day

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python Script I need to Stop/Skip the execution of a particular function for a day if the required condition gets false even for a single time. That means if a single error arises while the execution of particular function in my python script ...I want that function to become non-callable for a given duration of time and instead use alternate function for that particular duration. When the duration ends the function becomes again callable

Comment: Duration can be till End of the day

Comment: you can create a file that stores the time when the function will be available again. Then use `datetime.now()` to check if the current time is in the past or in the future of that time. Instead of a file you could also use Redis to store permanent values.

Comment: Thanks for answering...can we do this with any other way also?

Comment: There are different ways of doing that, all depend on your requirements. You can program  server that authorizes/denies execution and make your app request the server authorization to run certain features (similar to a license). This will add more security but also significantly increase complexity of your system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving your thought on this

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code next time to receive the proper help...

From what I understood, you need to start storing error times somehow.

```
if not your_required_condition:
    error_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - error_time).days >= 1:
        your_other_function()
    else:
        your_main_function()
```

You need to make your code check if the condition is verified each time...

Comment: Actually I am using a confidential API which has some request limits of 2500/day..If the API is requested even for 2-3 times more after the limit exceeds than the API key gets blocked and we are supposed to regenerate a new API key. I don't want the API key to get blocked hence using another API also of some low standard as an alternative to be called only when the first API  daily limit quota exceeds...hence if the limit exceeds for a given day than the calling of API shifts to another function which  will utilize the second API for that full day until the limits of first API resets next day.

Comment: Then the code still would work all you need to do is get the api response that explains that the limit had been reached. Or use a counter and increment it each time the api is called and once the counter reaches 2500 it just used the other function

Comment: Well ,thanks for giving your thought ,it helped